# How to use web3j to check the balance of an ERC20 custom Token and transfer the token to another wallet?

Tags: web3j

I'm studying to create wallets using infura, web3j, and android studio.

I am using ropsten testnet.
I have been able to check the amount of ethereum in my wallet and send ethereum to another account.

But I do not know how to check the balance of the custom token I issued and how to transfer it to another account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's an small snippet from my code, mine is also an custom token**

```java
        ERC20 javaToken = ERC20.load(contractAddress, web3, creds, 
        new DefaultGasProvider());//load contract

        EthBlockNumber blockNumber = web3.ethBlockNumber().send();
        
        System.out.println("erc20 class loaded");

        //to check balance use below code
        System.out.println("Balance of Account:'0xF01413046858033fbDC816B81DCef1E055ee8E42' :"
                + javaToken.balanceOf("0xF01413046858033fbDC816B81DCef1E055ee8E42").send() + "");
        BigInteger totalSuppy = javaToken.totalSupply().send();
        System.out.println("Total suppy of token is:\t" + totalSuppy);

        String symbol = javaToken.symbol().send();
        System.out.println("Information of token");
        String name = javaToken.name().send();
        BigInteger decimal = javaToken.decimals().send();
```

To transfer tokens use below code

```java
     TransactionReceipt receipt = 
  javaToken.transfer("0xdC99e1F3a42553C183B85FC760B3943eAe8539Ef", value).send();
        BigInteger blockNumber54 = receipt.getBlockNumber();

        BigInteger GasUsed = receipt.getGasUsed();
        List<Log> logs = receipt.getLogs();

          BigInteger balance = javaToken.balanceOf("0xdC99e1F3a42553C183B85FC760B3943eAe8539Ef").send();
        System.out.println("Balace of :'0xdC99e1F3a42553C183B85FC760B3943eAe8539Ef': " + balance.toString()
                + "\nTransaction Receipt:\t" + receipt + "\nInfo stored in 
   Block Number: " + blockNumber54
                + "\nGas Usage:" + GasUsed);
```